# $A_1, A_2 \subset X$ with disjoint closures in $X$, $cl_X(A_1)$ compact $\Rightarrow A_1, A_2$ have disjoint closures in $X_{\infty}$?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $A_1,A_2 \subset X$. Suppose that $\overline{A_1}^{X} \cap \overline{A_2}^{X}=\emptyset$ and $\overline{A_1}^{X}$ is compact. Let $X_\infty$ be the one-point compactification of $X$. Does this imply that $\overline{A_1}^{X_\infty} \cap \overline{A_2}^{X_\infty}=\emptyset$?

The only thing I could think was that $\overline{A_1}^{X}$ is closed in $X_\infty$. I was trying to work with the closures in $X$ and $X_\infty$ to see if I could get a relationship but unfortunately I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open sets in $X_\infty = X \cup \{ \infty\}$ are

- the open sets in $X$ and
- sets of the form $X_\infty \setminus A$ where $A \subseteq X$ is closed and compact in $X$.

By taking the complements, one sees that the closed sets in $X_\infty$ are

- sets of the form $A \cup \{\infty\}$ where $A \subseteq X$ is closed in $X$ and
- the closed *and* compact sets from $X$.

As you noted, $\overline{A_1}^X$ is closed in $X_\infty$. Therefore, $\overline{A_1}^{X_\infty} \subseteq \overline{A_1}^X$.

On the other hand, $\overline{A_2}^X \cup \{\infty\}$ is a closed set in $X_\infty$. This follows (by taking the complements) from the fact that $X \setminus \overline{A_2}^X$ is open in $X$ and thus open in $X_\infty$ as well. Hence, $\overline{A_2}^{X_\infty} \subseteq \overline{A_2}^X \cup \{ \infty\}$.

Putting things together we obtain
$$ \overline{A_1}^{X_\infty} \cap \overline{A_2}^{X_\infty} \subseteq \overline{A_1}^X \cap (\overline{A_2}^X \cup \{ \infty\}) = \emptyset. $$

Comment: Could you justify in more detail why $A \cup \{\infty\}$ is closed in $X_\infty$ if $A$ is closed in $X$?

Comment: That's because $A \cup \{ \infty\}$ is closed in $X_\infty$ iff $X_\infty \setminus (A \cup \{\infty\}) = X \setminus A$ is open in $X_\infty$ iff ($X \setminus A$ is open in $X$ or $X \setminus A = X_\infty \setminus B$ where $B$ is closed and compact in $X$). However, the latter is impossible since $\infty \not \in X \setminus A$. Therefore, the above chain can be continued: ... iff $X \setminus A$ is open in $X$ iff $A$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: More intuitively, we have that if $A \subset X$ is open in $X$ it is open in $X_\infty$ as well. Thus, its complement is closed in $X_\infty$. What is its complement in $X_\infty$? It is its complement in $X$ joined with $\infty$: $X_\infty \setminus A = (X \setminus A) \cup \{\infty\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!